# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el scroll del body , esté en el inicio tan solo haciendo un click en un botón?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, body

```
/*Javascript*/
body.classList.add("noScroll")
/*css*/
.NotScroll {
  overflow:hidden;
  /* !!!! */

}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que al oprimir un botón el scroll del body se vaya hacia arriba el inicio del scroll?.
He intentado buscar un solución por este sitio y no puede encontrar nada.

Comment: Hola Raul, recuerda que si eres nuevo puedes darle un vistazo a [ask]

Comment: Lo que quieres es volver arriba de la página mediante un botón "Up" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar el método [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) que permite hacer scroll a unas coordinadas específicas dentro de un elemento. Ejemplo:

```javascript
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```